# Case Class' Constructor with self-reference

Tags: scala

I have a case class `Folder`:

```
case class Folder(children: List[Folder], parent: Folder)
```

and a function which creates its children:

```
def createChildrenWith(parent: Folder) = ???
```

I want to pass the (self)-reference to the createChildrenWith within the constructor like:

```
Folder(createChildrenWith(<ref-to-Folder>), Nil)
```

while self is referring to the Folder that is currently being constructed.

How can I implement this?

PS: parent = Nil for top-level folder.

Comment: How are the child folders supposed to reference the parent?

Comment: updated. thanks for ur attention.

Comment: From what data are you generating these folders? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: Let say, we're building a random folder structure with recursive fashion for some tests with an input, depth, indicating the depth of the tree structure and numOfItems for the number of children at each level.

Answer (score 2):

You could use laziness.

```
class Folder(val name: String, p: => Option[Folder], c: => List[Folder]) {
  lazy val parent = p
  lazy val children = c
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    lazy val topFolder: Folder = new Folder("F1", None, List(c1, c2, c3))
    lazy val c1: Folder = new Folder("C1", Some(topFolder), List.empty)
    lazy val c2: Folder = new Folder("C2", Some(topFolder), List.empty)
    lazy val c3: Folder = new Folder("C3", Some(topFolder), List.empty)

    println(topFolder.children.head.parent.map(_.name).get) 
  }
}
```

However, I would personally look for a solution without circular references.

Comment: well, I'd come up with the idea as well. However, you need to write your own extractor in this case since you can not use Folder in pattern matching anymore. Ty for ur reply.